# How to get parameter from ros launch file and use it in Qt?

Tags: ros, roslauch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi
Im using ROS Fuerte and qt_ros so can integrate ROS in Qt GUI. I would like to use some parameters from the ROS launch file in my Qt GUI. in the main.cpp file of the GUI Im using the ROS launch file to start the prcess like this:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    //Roslaunch
    QProcess process;
    process.start("roslaunch", QStringList() << "/home/launch/pow.launch");
    //GUI
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    pow_gui::MainWindow w(argc,argv);
       w.show();
    app.connect(&app, SIGNAL(lastWindowClosed()), &app, SLOT(quit()));
    int result = app.exec();
    std::cout << "q application finished" << std::endl;
    return result;
}
```

So in my pow.launch launch fle

```
<launch>

    <param name="/use_sim_time" value="true"/>
    <node name="hector_mapping" pkg="hector_mapping" type="hector_mapping" output="screen">
 <param name="pub_map_odom_transform" value="false"/>
    <remap from="scan" to="scan_2"/>
 <param name="map_frame" value="map"/>

 </node>

    <node name="foo_throttler" type="throttle" pkg="topic_tools" args="messages /scan 10/scan_throttle" /> 
    <node name="foo_throttler1" type="throttle" pkg="topic_tools" args="messages /raw_imu 10/raw_imu_throttle" /> 

    <node name="rosplay" pkg="rosbag" type="play" args="/home/10m_forward5.bag --clock"/>
    <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="corner_duhhu" args="-0.17 -0.2 0 0 0 0 base_link laser 20"/> 

    <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="raw_tf" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 /map /raw_frame 10"/> 

    <!--node pkg="analyzer" type="parking"  name="parking" output="screen"/>  -->
    <node pkg="analyzer" type="wst_forward10m"  name="wst_forward10m" output="screen"/> 
    <!--node pkg="analyzer" type="wst_turn"  name="wst_turn" output="screen"/>  -->

</launch>
```

when Im using the node pkg="analyzer" type="wst_forward10m" name="wst_forward10m" I would like to have a tab in QT saying that Im using that node and when using node pkg="analyzer" type="wst_turn" name="wst_turn" would like to have that node displayed in QT.

Any help?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/186721/how-to-get-parameter-from-ros-launch-file-and-use-it-in-qt?/) by [pilot71](https://answers.ros.org/users/19738/pilot71/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-07-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-07-16**:
What are you trying to achieve? Calling roslaunch from within a binary seems very much backwards from its intended use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As you know, you need to get the contents of the launch file into a Qt for display. I'd think that the easiest way to do this would be to create your `QStringList` before the `process.start` line, then 'send' it to the `MainWindow` (by whatever means you'd like).

For instance -- and note that this is just a sketch, not implemented/tested -- you might have a `QTextEdit` widget as a member of the `MainWindow`. After `MainWindow` creation, you could simply do a `MainWindow->QTextEdit->setText(QStringList.join("\n"))`.

@dornhege, if one wants to be able to run everything in a single Qt executable, starting a `roslaunch` process is a decent option -- although in *this* case, because the launch file selection isn't embedded in the `MainWindow` and thus can't be chosen via Qt widget, I'd agree with you.

---

Originally posted by [kramer](https://answers.ros.org/users/2050/kramer/) with karma: 1470 on 2014-07-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0